# Can I cast abstract and interface classes (If i can than how will be cast)?

Tags: c#

I am trying to verify whether can i cast abstract and interface class . I have tried the following but can't get it so I assume I'm going about it the wrong way.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Also, the class structure would be interesting. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I searched about that question in Google but got not any specified ans so i put the question here that's why i got a correct ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. There can be quite a few possibilities to your question. I have tried to give them here. See if it fits your needs. If not then please comment

**Building of class structure**

```
public abstract class MyAbClass
{ 
    public abstract void MyM1();
}

public interface IMyInterface 
{
    void MyM2();
}

public class MyConcretClass1 : MyAbClass
{
    public override void MyM1()
    {
        //Your implementation here
    }
}

public class MyConcretClass2 : IMyInterface
{
    public void MyM2()
    {
        //Your implementation here
    }
}
```

**Possibilities**

```
//Following are the possibilities
//This can be done in some other class and passed to some other method
//maybe a factory pattern
MyAbClass cls1 = new MyConcretClass1();

//Will call method of MyConcretClass1
cls1.MyM1();

if (cls1 is MyConcretClass1)
{ 
    //Do casting here
}

var cls2 = cls1 as MyConcretClass1;

if (cls2 != null)
{ 
    //Do your stuff here
}


//This can be done in some other class and passed to some other method
//maybe a factory pattern
IMyInterface cls3 = new MyConcretClass2();

//Will call method of MyConcretClass2
cls3.MyM2();

if (cls3 is MyConcretClass2)
{
    //Do casting here
}

var cls4 = cls3 as MyConcretClass2;

if (cls4 != null)
{
    //Do your stuff here
}
```

Hope this helps